# How to chain methods in ruby passing the output of one method to consecutive methods

Tags: ruby, methods, chain

How can I pass the results of a method to another method in ruby?
eg:

```
class D
  def initialize(text)
    @text = text
  end

  def a s
    "hello #{s}"    
  end

  def b s
    "hi #{s}"
  end
end
```

So, what I want to do is pass the output of method a to method b. So essentially(if the methods aren't inside a class) I can do the following the following:

```
puts b(a "Tom") #=>hi hello Tom
```

However, even if this isn't inside a class, it wouldn't look good if there are a lot of methods so there must be a more elegant way to do this. So what is the proper way to get the output `hi hello Tom` by applying the methods a and b to an instance of the class D?

UPDATE
I just wanted to make it a little bit more clear. Eg, in F# you can do something like this:

```
let a s = "hello " + s
let b s = "hi " + s
"Tom" |> a |> b #=> hello hi Tom
```

Here we defined functions a and b and then passed on the results to the next function.
I know that its a functional language so ways of doing things would be different there. But I am just wondering if there are any such tricks in Ruby?

Comment: “so there must be a more elegant way to do this”—why is that? One might use `puts b a 'Tom'`, but I doubt it’s “more elegant.”

Comment: The question remains: why on the Earth you think that F#’s way is _more elegant_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can leave the `()`

```
def a s
  "hello #{s}"
end

def b s
  "hi #{s}"
end

puts b a "Tom"
```

If you have many methods :

```
puts [:a,:b].inject("Tom"){|result,method| self.send(method,result)}
```

If you want to use those methods with any object (including Classes) :

```
module Kernel
  def chain_methods(start_value, *methods)
    methods.inject(start_value){|result,method| self.send(method,result)}
  end
end

class D
  def a s
    "hello #{s}"
  end

  def b s
    "hi #{s}"
  end
end

class E
  class << self
    def a s
      "hello #{s}"
    end

    def b s
      "hi #{s}"
    end
  end
end


# Example with instance methods
puts D.new.chain_methods("Tom", :a, :b)

# Example with class methods
puts E.chain_methods("Tom", :a, :b)

# Thanks mudasobwa :
E.chain_methods("Tom", :a, :b, :puts)
```

Comment: Yay, upvoted for `puts [:a,:b].inject("Tom"){|result,method| Object.send(method,result)}` :) `puts` could be chained too, btw.

Comment: Wow, this is great! thanks Eric. Now, how can I get the same result if the methods are inside a class, in my example lets say class D, so how can I get the result by applying methods to an instance of class D? Or should I instead use class methods for that?

Comment: @BA you can define instance by `d = D.new("test")` and call `d.send` instead of `Object.send`

Comment: Why do you send the methods to `Object`? In the original code, they are sent to `self`, so you are calling completely different method. Although, please use `public_send` instead, there's no reason to break encapsulation here.

Comment: I wanted the code to also work when `a` and `b` are defined in main, since the OP mentioned it. In that case, they 
are private methods, available to every object.